# Accessing a local from one macro in another executed in the scope of the let

Tags: macros, clojure, symbol-capture

Be gentle, as my macrofoo is weak.

What I'd like to do is something like this:

```
(defmacro foo [x] `(dosync (alter x# conj x)))
(defmacro bar [] `(let [x# (ref [])] (foo 3)))
```

Is this possible? I can't just `(let [x ..] ..)` because of symbol capturing.

NOTE: I'm aware this example is trivial and not macro-worthy, but it's the simplest example I could come up with.

Comment: Any chance that you could provide a less simple, but more realistic example? I'm finding it really difficult to tell what you're trying to do (even given your own answer!). Just asking to understand what's going on, no worries if you'd rather move on. :-)

Comment: http://gist.github.com/381870 Is a better example of what I was trying to do. It still doesn't quite work because of an unrelated reason.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I needed to force symbol capturing.

```
(defmacro foo [x] `(dosync (alter ~'x conj x)))
(defmacro bar [] `(let [~'x (ref [])] (foo 3)))
```

Although dangerous if you don't understand macros thoroughly, this works.

Comment: I think you're missing syntax-quote in both of those. (Also see my comment on the question.)

Comment: Yeah, I forgot to add that. Sorry.